# Why can't I select this? - Selenium

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, element

The following thing is *embedded* into a webpage. It is not part of the actual site:

[image]

What I've been trying to do is select the 'previous meetings' tab, using Selenium in Python.

These are the elements for both buttons (upcoming meetings and previous):

```html
<div role="tab" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true" class="ant-tabs-tab-active ant-tabs-tab" tabindex="0" aria-label="Upcoming Meetings">Upcoming Meetings</div>
  ::before
  Upcoming Meetings
</div>
<div role="tab" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false" class=" ant-tabs-tab" aria-label="Previous Meetings">Previous Meetings</div>
   ::before
   Previous Meetings
</div>
```

I've tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class=" ant-tabs-tab"]').click()` but that didn't detect the element.

When I view the actual source code of the webpage, these Zoom elements didn't show up, so I think that's why Selenium doesn't recognise it either.

It doesn't have an ID or anything else, so I can't try them. Is there anything I *can* do? (e.g. Just click a location on the screen)

Or am I doing something wrong?

It seems to be an iframe, starting with

```
<iframe src="about:blank" name="tool_content" id="tool_content" class="tool_launch" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" tabindex="0" title="Tool Content" style="height:100%;width:100%;" allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *; midi *; encrypted-media *; autoplay *" data-lti-launch="true"></iframe>
```

If that helps.

## Update:

I tried using an extension for Firefox that gave you the *exact* xpath of an element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]').click()
```

And this still didn't work - how come??

Comment: Try css selector "div.ant-tabs-tab-active.ant-tabs-tab" instead. Also your class was incorrect.

Comment: @arundeepchohan So then the line would look like this instead? `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.ant-tabs-tab-active.ant-tabs-tab').click()` Sorry, I haven't used the css selector before.

Comment: That's what it would look like.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Also `ant-tabs-tab` seems to have a space before it, so what should I do there? Because right now I'm getting this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: div.ant-tabs-tab-active.ant-tabs-tab`

Comment: spaces generally means it's a compound class.

Comment: Is there anything like an iframe in the page source?

Comment: @arundeepchohan WAIT THERE IS AN IFRAME TAG. What should I do then??? I've added the start of that iframe tag to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: driver.switch_to.frame("tool_content")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222166/discussion-between-arundeep-chohan-and-scob).

Comment: @arundeepchohan Nevermind - It worked for me! Using `switch_to.frame` and then doing `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]').click()` worked!!!! Feel free to put this as an answer and I'm happy to mark it as the solution!

Comment: Did you delay the find element, for waithing the page to load?

Comment: Yes - turns out I just had to switch to the `iframe` that the Zoom frame was in, otherwise it wouldn't be recognised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to having an iframe  just switch to it

```
driver.switch_to.frame("tool_content")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And just one last thing - how would I switch back from the iframe, to the regular webpage again?

Comment: driver.switch_to.default_content()

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_class_name("tool_launch"))`